# Parity chain specification - use remote file?

Tags: parity, command-line

When using Parity with a private blockchain, you type:

$ parity --chain /path/to/chainspec.json

I wonder if there is a way to make this chain spec remote?  Could be useful when using multiple nodes.  Something like:

$ parity --chain http://aws.instance.com/chainspec.json